# file which is being uploaded to google drive is not retaining it's name . [https://developers.google.com/drive/v3/web/simple-upload]

Tags: python, google-api, google-drive-api, google-api-python-client

here is the code.

```
def uploadFile(filename,filepath,mimetype):

    file_metadata = {'name': filename}
    media = MediaFileUpload(filepath,mimetype=mimetype)

   file = drive_service.files().insert(body={'name': 
   filename},media_body=media,convert=True,ocr=True).execute()

   print('File ID: %s' % file.get('id'))
   return file.get('id')
```

drive api version used is v2. 
i am using this scopes, 
scope=['https://www.googleapis.com/auth/drive'] which gives me read write permission. where and what should i look forward to make sure the filename is retained after upload . filename is getting changed to Untitled.

is it permission issue or some other problem ?

Answer (score 0):

I am a little confused becouse your title links

> https://developers.google.com/drive/v3/web/simple-upload

Which is the sample for using Google Drive v3.   Yet you state in your question that you are using

> drive api version used is v2.

Google Drive V2 file name is title and not name.  Google Drive v3 uses name.

```
file_metadata = {'title': 'photo.jpg'}
media = MediaFileUpload('files/photo.jpg',
                        mimetype='image/jpeg')
file = drive_service.files().insert(body=file_metadata,
                                    media_body=media,
                                    fields='id').execute()
print 'File ID: %s' % file.get('id')
```

documentation for upload with v2 [Upload](https://developers.google.com/drive/v2/web/manage-uploads)

Comment: sorry , the documentation which i was viewing at that time was of v3 . this problem is resolved : yes Dalmto you are right the problem was that i was not using the key 'title' . thanks.